# how many updates a record in postgresql support?

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating an app where I sotore the **transactions of a bank account**, I update the **bank total_amout** with each transaction (denormalization), I would like to know how many updates it's possible to make to one record?, because each new transaction updates a bank account.

Answer (score 5):

Within each transaction, 4 billion. And between vaccums, 4 billion transactions. As long as you vacuum regularly, and commit at least once every 4 billion updates, no limit.

Comment: What happens if you don't vacuum or don't commit every 4 billion records?  Does my data go bad?

Comment: If you don't commit ever 4bn cmds, you get an error. If you don't vacuum every 4bn trans, database shuts down and forces you to do it (actually, it likely did it for you in the background before you got there, but in case it failed..) Your data is, of course, safe.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of updates to a single row in a table.